# Bash grep regex to include minus as character set

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I would like to include the minus sign as part of my capture.
As you can see below I tried to escape the minus sign. But as you run the query, it is obvious the minus sign is not included, not colored.

```
TEST="arquillian-bom"
echo $TEST|grep --color -E "[0-9|a-z|\-|\.|\_]+"
arquillian-bom
```

Also to verify that it is not included:

```
echo $TEST|grep --color -o -E "[0-9|a-z|\-|\.|\_]+"
arquillian
bom
```

I'm using the bash on Mac OSX

```
grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Any idea how to include the minus sign, or to escape this minus sign properly? I tried `\-` or `\\-` or `\\\-` they all failed.

Comment: `-` must be at the end of the bracket expression, use `"[0-9a-z._-]+"`